# KnockoutJS virtual/ wildcard (*) element or similar behavior?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Wondering if there's any way to bind an observable array to an element that is defined by a value (object, array, string, ..) in that array. For example, if I had:

```
var elements = ko.observableArray(['h1','p','blockquote']);
```

After applying the viewmodel bindings, I'd have a button for inserting each one of them, how would I go about doing the template? Instinctively, I wanted something like:

```
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach: elements">
  <!-- ko html: '<' + $data + '>' + '</' + $data + '>' -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

But as I suspected, KnockoutJS tells me:

> Message: The binding 'html' cannot be used with virtual elements

Solution?

Comment: You don't want to do that. Don't create dependencies from your data to your presentation. Your data should not dictate your HTML. Find an abstraction. (Maybe it helps to outline why you have that idea in the first place.)

Comment: Interesting point @Tomalak. Assume that this code would serve a blog post snippet generator, how would you allow the user to insert different HTML elements? The way I see it, in this case, your data **IS** your presentation, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You have data (which happens to include a string of characters that further happens to be HTML) and you have your presentation (your view with - say - a container div). For this situation there is the `html` binding. For all your data side is concerned, it's encapsulating a string. Your view alone should decide how to use that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with a custom binding this is completely possible.

So we just build our own binding called changeTag:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.changeTag = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).replaceWith('<'+bindingContext.$data+'></'+bindingContext.$data+'>');
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

    }
};
```

Then apply that binding to the html.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <div data-bind="changeTag:{}"><div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question but I think that's what you want.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/H5rk6/1/

Comment: Yes, this absolutely rocks! Although this is indeed the answer for my initial question & the most concise solution, I'd like to mention that I feel like @Tomalak's answer is the most correct/ structured way to use the KnockoutJS MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Extending from my comments to your question. Let's assume your data represents a series of blog posts and each one is broken up into items.

```
var blogData = {
    "title": "My Blog",
    "posts": [
        {
            "title": "First Post",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "paragraph",
                    "content": "The first paragraph."
                },
                {
                    "type": "paragraph",
                    "content": "The second paragraph."
                },
                {
                    "type": "quote",
                    "by": "Somebody important",
                    "content": "Quote text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

You could work with dynamic templates, like this:

```html
<h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <div class="post">
        <h2 data-bind="text: title"></h2>
        <div data-bind="foreach: items">
            <!-- ko template: {name: 'item-' + type} --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="item-paragraph">
    <p data-bind="text: content"></p>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="item-quote">
    <blockquote data-bind="text: content, attr: {title: by}"></blockquote>
</script>
```

and a plain

```
ko.applyBindings(blogData);
```

This way you can decouple the actual presentation from your data.

Minimal fiddle [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9h2/).

Comment: I can't accept this as "answer" because it doesn't provide the most direct answer to my initial question. But for sure it looks like the best way to handle this situation. +1 Thx for all the feedback. See my comment on @Thunda's answer,

Comment: I don't really care for the accept so no need to apologize. If it helped you in some way that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "ko if" to check what kind of element it is. I know it'd be a bit verbose, but that's the only way I know of to do something like that.

```
<!-- ko if: $data == "h1" -->
<h1></h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

etc. etc.

Or rather...

```
<h1 data-bind="if: $data == 'h1'"></h1>
<p data-bind="if: $data == 'p'"></p>
<blockquote data-bind="if: $data == 'blockquote'"></blockquote>
```

Comment: Ah so you mean creating an `if` binding for every element in the array with its own HTML?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I don't know if there's a better solution (I hope there is), but I've never seen one.

Comment: I've been searching for it in vain, and I'm hoping maybe it is possible through extending Knockout with custom bindings or so. The solution you propose is good enough for my case (+1), but I'm still wondering whether someone can come up with something clever...

Comment: Ditto. I'd like a more elegant solution, but at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $data property of your array. Here is a similar working example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrathchild77/YbLv6/2/

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <h1 data-bind="if: $data == 'h1'">Heading 1</h1>
    <p data-bind="if: $data == 'p'">paragraph</p>
    <blockquote data-bind="if: $data == 'blockquote'">blockquote</blockquote>
</div>

$(function () {
    var baseModel = {
        // data
        elements: ko.observableArray(['h1', 'p', 'blockquote'])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(baseModel);
});
```

Comment: He's not trying to create divs with the text property set to the name of the tag. He's trying to create a different tag, dynamically chosen based on what $data is. 

If $data is "p", then there should be a <p></p>
If $data is "h1", then there should be <h1></h1>

In your example, he'd always get a div.

Comment: My mistake, Thank you. I updated the fiddle with the correct implementation.

Comment: Hey swestfall, did you make a new fiddle? The link that you have in your answer is still creating divs.

Thanks

Edit: Ah, nevermind. I see that you updated your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I did, thank you. I updated it to point to the new version of the fiddle.